# I want to call the upcoming events in sidebar.php file without using widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, all-in-one-event-calendar

Hi I am using All in one event calender for my website. I want to show the upcoming events in sidebar of page without using widget(means it provides the drag and drop widget but i don't want to use that), i want to call the function of upcoming events in 'sidebar.php' and show upcoming events on page?

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the shortcode of your plugin directly in the sidebar.php template file. Edit sidebar.php and add the following code where you want the event calendar to appear: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[ai1ec view="monthly"]'); ?>`
You must replace the code between single quote with your desired plugin shortcode. You maybe have to play a little bit with the code, depending on the theme you use. I am ready to help if you have any problems.

Comment: I also used the do_shortcode() function but it is not working. I am just trying it on twentytwelve theme. I remove the below line from sidebar.php : dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); but not working

Comment: Thanks Dragos, it was not working on that theme, I changed it and working. Again Thanks.

Comment: I make it working for twentytwelve theme. Do you want to find out how?

Comment: Thanks, Actually i use different theme for my project, but just I was trying on twentytwelve the theme.

Comment: Ok, glad I could help. Have a nice day and good luck with your project!